# Passing parameters to parallel R jobs

Tags: r, parameter-passing, parallel-processing

I am trying to run parallel R jobs using the *multicore* package. Every job is the execution of the same `script.R` with different arguments.

A general idea is to define a function that takes the args and then calls `source("script.R")`. The problem is that I cannot pass the args to the `script.R`. Since I am running in parallel the args cannot be defined in the global scope.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: If multicore supports some way of setting variables in the global environment on each core, you could use that. Personally I use snowfall for parallel processing and am very happy with it (and supports these kind of things easily)

Comment: I am kind of new to R parallel processing and multicore is the first library I am using. I'll take a look at snowfall. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the snowfall package.  I wrote a blog post that walks through what I think you want to do, using snowfall: http://bit.ly/xaWAx6

Answer (score 0):

As running parallel R instances which might be even on different nodes/computers, using an outer database to store parameters might be a good option.

I would use [redis](http://redis.io/) as being extremely fast and fully [accessible in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rredis/index.html), and for parallel runs its brother: [doredis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRedis/index.html).

So you could have a redis server (or even a replicated, slave database on every host) which could be fetched for parameters. You could instantly update the parameters even from outside of R available to all workers and could easily add new workers for the task with doredis.